# LVM Full disk encryption on two disks with single passphrase

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, encryption, lvm

I have two disks, and want to have all storage managed by LVM and fully encrypted. However, the Ubuntu installer only offers the choice to set this up for one of the disks. How can I set it up so ALL space is included in the LVM encryption scheme?

Answer (score 0):

LUKS only encrypts one device, so you could put LVM outside of LUKS - creating a LVM out of the multiple drives, then use LUKS inside it.

The installer can't do that automatically, good guides abound on the web saying how to do it, could be rather long.